# List<T> adding item

Tags: c#

I have a model like this:

```
class PayPalModel
{
    public class Payment
    {
        public string intent { get; set; }
        public Payer payer { get; set; }
        public List<Transaction> transactions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Payer
    {
        public string payment_method { get; set; }
        public List<Funding_Instruments> funding_instruments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Funding_Instruments
    {
        public Credit_Card credit_card { get; set; }
    }

    public class Credit_Card
    {
        public string number { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int expire_month { get; set; }
        public int expire_year { get; set; }
        public string cvv2 { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public Billing_Address billing_address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Billing_Address
    {
        public string line1 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postal_code { get; set; }
        public string country_code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Transaction
    {
        public Amount amount { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Amount
    {
        public string total { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public Details details { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        public string subtotal { get; set; }
        public string tax { get; set; }
        public string shipping { get; set; }
    }


}
```

And I am trying to add values to it but I am getting stuck on how to add `funding_instruments`.

I have tried the following but it won't let me add a new `Credit_Card`

This is my code:

```
PayPalWrapper.PayPalModel.Payment payment = new PayPalWrapper.PayPalModel.Payment();

        payment.intent = "sale";
        payment.payer = new PayPalWrapper.PayPalModel.Payer();
        payment.payer.payment_method = "credit_card";

        payment.payer.funding_instruments = new List<PayPalWrapper.PayPalModel.Funding_Instruments>();
        payment.payer.funding_instruments.Add(new PayPalModel.Credit_Card() { first_name = "test" });
```

But it is giving the error

```
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PayPalWrapper.PayPalModel.Funding_Instruments>.Add(PayPalWrapper.PayPalModel.Funding_Instruments)' has some invalid arguments
```

I just cannot work out the syntax for adding a Credit_Card!

Can anyone help please?

Comment: @Jontatas Paypal documentation probably wouldn't help you with this issue. It's a case of adding the wrong type to a list, that is all.

Comment: Be sure to read the entire error message. It should be along the lines of ` cannot convert from 'PayPalWrapper.PayPalModel.Credit_Card' to 'PayPalWrapper.PayPalModel.Funding_Instruments'`. That's a clear indicator of what you're doing wrong.

Comment: thanks for the down votes! - we all have to learn....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because you are adding the wrong type...

You have declared `funding_instruments` as being `List<Funding_Instruments>` but trying to add a new `Credit_Card`. To make it work it should look more like this:

```
payment.payer.funding_instruments.Add(new PayPalModel.Funding_Instruments 
{ 
    credit_card = new PayPalModel.Credit_Card
    {
        first_name = "test"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no relationship between `Funding_Instruments` and `Credit_Card`You have a strongly typed `List<Funding_Instruments>` and you are trying add a new item of type `Credit_Card` to your list.You can't do that.Maybe your intention was adding new `Funding_Instruments` by setting the `credit_card` property like this:

```
payment.payer.funding_instruments.Add(new Funding_Instruments
        {
            credit_card = new Credit_Card() {first_name = "test"}
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list is one of type `Funding_Instruments` ... however, you are trying to add an item of type `Credit_Card` which will never work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
    payment.payer.funding_instruments.Add(new PayPalModel.Credit_Card() { first_name = "test" });
```

with

```
var fi = new Funding_Instrument();
fi.credit_card = new PayPalModel.Credit_Card() { first_name = "test" };
payment.payer.funding_instruments.Add(fi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding wrong type hence this error.
Please change your code:

**From :**

```
payment.payer.funding_instruments.Add(new PayPalModel.Credit_Card() { first_name = "test" });
```

**To:**

```
payment.payer.funding_instruments.Add(new PayPalModel.Funding_Instruments 
{ 
    credit_card = new PayPalModel.Credit_Card
    {
        first_name = "test"
    }
});
```